# I would like to propose a tag for Philips Hue

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Finally we've got a chance to have a site for this long-standing out of scope topic! Thanks guys!

I would like to propose the creation of a "philips-hue" tag. While it's a very specific vendor-related tag, there are many Hug devices in the world, so probably many visitors will benefit from it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to create a tag is to apply it to a question, either when initially posting the question or by editing the question. Tags are not created preemptively, and conversely tags are deleted automatically (after a small delay) if they are removed from every question.

So if you think that a question should have the tag [philips-hue](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philips-hue), then add the tag to the question. And if there's no applicable question, then we don't need the tag (yet).

There's no need to open a meta discussion for every tag, only when there's some doubt about the usefulness, scope or name of the tag.

Answer (score 1):

I agree and I think it's a prudent way to create a tag named [philips-hue](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philips-hue), we could possibly make [hue](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hue) a synonym from the start.

Generally speaking our main product related tags should have the company name in it unless the trademark is super clear on its own, which *hue* as a normal English word isn't.